# Add White Space Between Checkboxlist Text and Checkbox

Tags: html, css, asp.net, webforms, checkboxlist

I am attempting to use a cssclass to add whitespace.  I have coded with the below, but I am not getting any extra whitespace.

What is the proper way to code for this?

```
.checkboxlistformat {
    margin-left:30px;
}


<div align="center" runat="server" id="checkboxlistdiv">
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="checkboxlisttest" CssClass="checkboxlistformat" runat="server" RepeatLayout="table" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="vertical" OnSelectedIndexChanged="checkboxlist_SIC_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:CheckBoxList>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your ASP generates a corresponding `<label>` for the text. You can target the text with an ancestor descendant selector as `.checkboxlistformat label`:

```css
.checkboxlistformat label {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<input id="checkboxlisttest" type="checkbox" class="checkboxlistformat">
<label for="checkboxlisttest">Checkbox</label>
```

Alternatively, you could always simply place the margin on the **right** of the checkbox:

```css
.checkboxlistformat {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<input id="checkboxlisttest" type="checkbox" class="checkboxlistformat">
<label for="checkboxlisttest">Checkbox</label>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I am populating the checkboxlist from a dataset on page load.  Does that affect the syntax?

Comment: Nope - CSS is applied after page load. Assuming your output generates the `<label>`, the above will work. If not, you'll probably need to showcase your rendered output.

Comment: Hmm...something else must be interfering then because it is just not adding the whitespace for me.  I even set the margin-right to 60px to make sure :)

Comment: I got it --- it should be .checkboxlistformat label {}

Comment: This won't work as the css class is not applied to the label, just the parent element (which could be a span or table or ul or ol depending on the RepeatLayout of the CheckBoxList. Removing the plus to make it an ancestor descendant selector should work.

Comment: Then please post your rendered HTML output, and also check the F12 Developer Tools. You may need to clear your cache as well. If you can show the output that you end up with after the ASP runs, I can confirm if the selector is valid or not. Don't forget that you can always try with less specificity. You may find `.checkboxlistformat ~ label`, `.checkboxlistformat label` or even just `label` works for you. If  `label` works, then you definitely have a label, and it's not in the usual order. If `label` doesn't work, then you may have a caching issue.  ... Glad you got it in the end :)